# Maganto 2 | Does guest customer Id exists ? if yes how can we get through Order collection or some other way?

Tags: magento2, customer, guest-checkout, edit-order

I am getting guest customer Collection with:

```
\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
```

as:

```
public function getGuestOrderCollection()
  {    
   $orderCollecion = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('*');
   $orderCollecion->addAttributeToFilter('customer_is_guest', ['eq'=>1]);
   return $orderCollecion;
  }
```

Currently I am not getting ID for guest customer by this but it works without guest customer:

```
$Id = $_order->getId();
```

I am looking to change guest customer information by this. Can any body help  me to now about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no customer id returns for guest. The `$Id` you got is actually `order_id`. If you want to change the guest customer info, you can use the following code for an order:

```
$_order->setCustomerEmail("newemail@host.com"); //Set "Email"
```

If you want to modify the addresses, you can use the following code:

```
$bill_address = $order->getBillingAddress();
$bill_address->setTelephone(12345678);  //Set "Telephone" inside billing address
$ship_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
$ship_address->setTelephone(98765432);  //Set "Telephone" inside shipping address
```

Comment: yes it is setting the updated email by this way but when I get email addresses of all orders it shows old email address  for that order number and not the updated one..

Comment: Do you have `$_order->save()` in the end?

Comment: Yes I have $_order->save() in the end

Comment: That's strange. How about adding save immediately after setCustomerEmail?

Comment: It worked this time.